# Always get Response back APIs?

Tags: web-services, rest, tdd

I forget, is there ever a situation where you may not get an http response back?  Let's say you send a request to some API, and it bombs on their side.  They're supposed to set a status code if that happens but I assume there have to be times where there could be other variables that could fail in which you might not get a response back.

I'm trying to setup some of my TDD. I think testing whether I get a non-null response back is a good first 'simplest as possible' test to start out with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would suggest that having a test for checking only that response is not null is almost worthless. TDD is not about writing infinite little tests to develop something (like testing that constructor actually creates an object etc.), but that is another topic altogether.

Back on the topic, there could be a situation where the network fails, so you wouldn't get a response at all.

Comment: you have a point, a first test can test something else that could fail if a response is ever null anyway